# "Input string was not in a correct format" when using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I am trying to do a `FirstOrDefault()` query on an Object Set and a weird exception is thrown:

**My Code:**

```
private RecordObject GetRecordByID(int recID)
{
    return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault(rec => rec.ID == recID);
}
```

**Exception Message:**

> Input string was not in a correct format

`InnerException` is null.

**Stack Trace:**

```
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&         number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

The weird thing is that I'm not doing any type conversions.

**P.S:** The database is Oracle 10g, but since I'm using EF, I guess this does not matter but just in case you need this detail.

Comment: Does just doing FirstOrDefault() returns a value ?

Comment: Can you write what format in db table is your id?

Comment: I had today exactly same error and the problem was I inserted data as integer and in database field was char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've sorted this out and I will keep this question in case someone has the same problem.

To solve it, I needed to re-import my tables from the database, apparently, there was some incompatible column(s) between my ADO.Net objects and the database.

I think, EF was trying to make a Cast operation to compensate for my mistake (leaving non-compatible versions), and the cast is not possible, and this is where the type-conversion came from.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not comparing int with null column in database (ID) .

P.S. the passed recId is not null but values which it is checked against may be null in database table

Comment: recID is of type int in the method, also it would be a compile time error

Comment: No, there is no compile time errors, since I provided a stack trace, this means it is a run-time error.

Comment: What i meant is that to check if the mapped entity column (Id in this case) is not defined as a null column(column allows null values in database)