# Oracle EF - DataDbContext.SaveChanges() throws Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, insert

im using c# with Entityframework to access to a Oracle database. After update the entities on the model, i'm just adding a new entity do a dbset, then i call dbcontext.SaveChanges(), and a exception is thrown "Input string was not in a correct format."

As Oracle does not have autonumbers, i've changed the "StoreGeneratedPattern" to Identity and the table where i'm tring to add a row have a relation to other table.

i'm missing something too basic?
some ideas?

```
myentity oNew = new myentity(){...}

ctx.myentity.Add(oNew);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: do any of the values you're trying to add to the oNew object, exceed limits placed on specific columns in the DB?  i.e do you have a string that is too long to be input into a column? or are the data types out of synch?

Comment: This user had the same exception with an Oracle EF setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430637/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-when-using-linq

Comment: @Madullah i've checked thousand times the values noting exceeds the ecpected limits. maybe it happens inside the oracle provider and my debugger is catching tooo much exceptions, because, if i surround it on a try catch statement, the exception is never catched...